# richfaces show modalPanel if long page loading time, not showing modalPanel when page load fast

Tags: richfaces

I use modalpanl to prevent user clicking on submit button multiple times like following code.
however, when there is a form validation on same page, it brings modal panel out as well. because validation is a very fast process, modal panel got brought out and got cleared in a very short time .like 0.5 sec. it looks like a flash to user and it makes bad user experience. 
is there anyway to show modalPanel only when it takes more than 1 sec to load a page.

> onclick="Richfaces.showModalPanel('InProgress');"
>   oncomplete="Richfaces.hideModalPanel('InProgress');"

Comment: Don't think there is a simple way to achieve this. Just don't show the modal panel when validating.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to prevent the form from multiple submissions . You can simply disable the submit button using its  `onclick` attribute . In the form validation process , in case of any validation errors , the submit button should enable back .

When the action method of the submit button finishes ,and if the submit button 's `rendered` attribute does not depend on any Mbean value ,  you can simply enable back the submit button using its `oncomplete`  attribute .  If the  submit button 's `rendered` attribute depends on some MBean 's properties and there are chances that these properties will be changed in action method , then you should `reRender` the submit button.

For example ,

If the submit button 's `rendered` attribute does not depend on any Mbean value

```
<a4j:commandButton id="submitBtn" value="Submit" action="#{MBean.action}" onclick="this.disabled=true" oncomplete="this.disabled=false"/>
```

If  the submit button 's `rendered` attribute depends on some  Mbean value

```
<a4j:commandButton id="submitBtn" value="Submit" action="#{MBean.action}" onclick="this.disabled=true" rendered="#{MBean.someValue}"  reRender="#{rich:clientId('submitBtn')}"/>
```

I think this approach is more straightforward , easier to understand and maintainable than using the `ModalPanel` approach to block the form from multiple submissions .

Comment: Hi Ken, I use the same thing as yours, but if there is a large form to submit, which may take 5~10 seconds, it is better to show a modal panel or a progress bar, otherwise the user may leave current page. What do you think? Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin , I think you may try to use `a4j:push` to display a message something likes `the form is submitting , please wait` to inform the user.You can look at the demo to see what `a4j:push` can do at http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/push.jsf?tab=usage&cid=688408 .I did not try it before but it seems possible.